# draggable without jQuery ui

Tags: javascript, draggable

How to make a element draggable without using jQuery UI?

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_coords(event)
    {
        var x=event.clientX;
        var y=event.clientY;
        var drag=document.getElementById('drag');
        drag.style.left=x;
        drag.style.top=y
    }
</script>

<body style="height:100%;width:100%" onmousemove="show_coords(event)">
     <p id="drag" style="position:absolute">drag me</p>
</body>
```

The problem is that I want to drag while the user the pressing the mouse button. I tried `onmousedown` but results were negative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will be quite easy as you get the concept.

```
function enableDragging(ele) {
    var dragging = dragging || false,        //Setup a bunch of variables
        x, y, Ox, Oy,
        enableDragging.z = enableDragging.z || 1,
        current;
    ele.onmousedown = function(ev) {         //When mouse is down
        current = ev.target;
        dragging = true;                     //It is dragging time
        x = ev.clientX;                      //Get mouse X and Y and store it
        y = ev.clientY;                      // for later use.
        Ox = current.offsetLeft;             //Get element's position
        Oy = current.offsetTop;
        current.style.zIndex = ++enableDragging.z;  //z-index thing

        window.onmousemove = function(ev) {
            if (dragging == true) {                //when it is dragging
                var Sx = ev.clientX - x + Ox,      //Add the difference between
                    Sy = ev.clientY - y + Oy;      // 2 mouse position to the
                current.style.top = Sy + "px";     // element.
                current.style.left = Sx + "px";
                return false;                      //Don't care about this.
            }
        };
        window.onmouseup = function(ev) {
            dragging && (dragging = false);        //Mouse up, dragging done!
        }
    };
}

enableDragging(document.getElementById("drag"));  //draggable now!

var ele = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++){              //Every div's is draggable
    enableDragging(ele[i]);                       // (only when its "position"
}                                                 //  is set to "absolute" or
                                                  //  "relative")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/NWU9G/

The reason why your code is not working is because the `<div>` will always follow where your cursor goes, and you are not actually *dragging* it. The top left corner will always follow your cursor, and this is not we wanted.

---

### UPDATE

Now if you only want a grabber or something similar, just change this part of the script:

```
ele.onmousedown = function(ev) {
    current = ev.target;
```

to

```
var grabber = document.createElement("div");
grabber.setAttribute("class", "grabber");
ele.appendChild(grabber);
grabber.onmousedown = function(ev) {
    current = ev.target.parentNode;
```

Now you can only click on the grabber to start the dragging process.

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/NWU9G/7/

Comment: Thanks but i wanted that there can be a dot or any other thing at left-top corner of the draggable element and the box could only be dragged by holding mouse pointer on the corner, can tell me how to do this. And once again thanks.

Comment: That's great i didn't thought i would be able to do this without jQuery ui. But i did, thanks to you.

Comment: Thanks, and if you found it helping, you can check the checkmark under the votecounts.

Comment: what does checking that checkmark means. Please explain i am a NewUser

Comment: and do a last favour, can you set the cursor ,the one which is seen when move option on a window, the one with arrow on all four sides. And tell what does checking that checkbox mean

Comment: @NewUser - Use `cursor: move` for the cursor, and the checkmark means you think the answer checked is the best among all answers.

Comment: @Derek I use this make upload file be draggable but if user after drag current files, then continued upload file and drag, the file not the highest zindx. can tell me how to do this? Thanks so much!!

Comment: @user1775888 - Take a look at my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/NWU9G/7/), `Line 16` makes sure the last dragged element is on the top. (highest z-index)

Comment: @user1775888 - I don't really understand your question.

Comment: Chrome 76.0.3809.132 64 bit  errored on the var instantiation line `enableDragging.z = enableDragging.z || 1,` so I commented it out (also `current.style.zIndex = ++enableDragging.z;`). Charming success!