# How to make img draggable and wrap move too

Tags: javascript, jquery

below code try to make img be draggable(regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10965447/1775888)), it works but I can't figure how to make if img move all wrap `drag_wp` move together. http://jsfiddle.net/cAeKG/8/ any suggestion?

js

```
function enableDraggin(el){
    var dragging = dragging || false, x, y, ox, oy, current;
    el.onmousedown = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        current = e.target;
        dragging = true;
        x = e.clientX;
        y = e.clientY;
        ox = current.offsetLeft;
        oy = current.offsetTop;
        window.onmousemove = function(e) {
            if (dragging == true) {
                var sx = e.clientX - x + ox,
                sy = e.clientY - y + oy;
                current.style.left = sx + "px";
                current.style.top = sy + "px";
                return false;
            }
        };
        window.onmouseup = function(e) {
            dragging && (dragging = false);
        };
    };
};
var el = $('.drag_wp');
for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
    enableDragging(el[i]);
};
```

html & css

```
<div class="drag_wp">
    <img src="..." class="drag_el">
    <div></div>
    ....// other div
</div>
.drag_wp{
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background:red;
}
.drag_el{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Note that you have a typo: function is called `enableDraggin` and in for loop you have `enableDragging` (`g` at the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function enableDraggin(el){
    var dragging = dragging || false, x, y, ox, oy, current;
    el.onmousedown = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        current = e.target;
        //just add this
        if(!$(current).hasClass(".drag_wp"))
             current = $(current).closest(".drag_wp")[0];
        //just add this
        dragging = true;
        x = e.clientX;
        y = e.clientY;
        ox = current.offsetLeft;
        oy = current.offsetTop;
        window.onmousemove = function(e) {
            if (dragging == true) {
                var sx = e.clientX - x + ox,
                sy = e.clientY - y + oy;
                current.style.left = sx + "px";
                current.style.top = sy + "px";
                return false;
            }
        };
        window.onmouseup = function(e) {
            dragging && (dragging = false);
        };
    };
};
```

`e.target` returns element that was clicked (image in most cases for your HTML). If it has no class `.drag_wp`, just find closest parent with that class and use it as current.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fTeXL/

Also, as you are already using jquery, you may find it better to use corresponding plugin from jQuery UI:  http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Thanks for reply. it works!!  I'm learning try to make it work without ui or plugin.

Comment: is it possible make if click one of inner div and the all wrap won't move? because I try to bind another function click 1 div to rotate or resize wp.

Comment: Yes. You can check it with something like hasClass, and if target has that class, say "resize_rotate", than do not execute drag code. But another option is to put `return false;` in that second function or use `e.stopPropagation()` http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/, so event will never be fired on `.drag_wp` element where you dragging code is attached.

Comment: Thanks so much, I put the e.stopPropagation in the rotate function after mousedown, work great!

Answer (score 1):

I made some modifications to your code:

```
function enableDragging(el) {
    var dragging = dragging || false,
        x, y, ox, oy, current;
    el.onmousedown = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        current = e.target.parentNode; // <--- current should be wrapper, not image
        dragging = true;
        x = e.clientX;
        y = e.clientY;
        ox = current.offsetLeft;
        oy = current.offsetTop;
        window.onmousemove = function (e) {
            if (dragging == true) {
                var sx = e.clientX - x + ox,
                    sy = e.clientY - y + oy;
                current.style.left = sx + "px";
                current.style.top = sy + "px";
                return false;
            }
        };
        window.onmouseup = function (e) {
            dragging && (dragging = false);
        };
    };
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cAeKG/9/

Comment: `e.target.parentNode` will not work if image is not a direct child of `.drag_wp`. Just the same as if `mousedown` happens on `.drag_wp` directly.